# Understanding `WHERE x = NEW.x` Syntax

Tags: trigger, update, sqlite3

I'm writing an application that uses SQLite to store court information obtained from a government database in a `client` table. I've set up a [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=13d8556c979807f2b4bb6d6bfd7e6636) here, which is a simplification of my application.

- The first time a request is made to the database, the `clients` table will be populated with the information.
- When the user wants to check if there are any updates, a new request will be made and the results will be inserted into a `client_update` table
- Upon insertion on the `client_update` table, I will run a trigger that will update the `client` table if any of the columns of `client_update` have new information. If the `client` table is updated, the original row from the `client` table should be logged in a `log` table

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67136895/update-and-log-only-changed-rows-with-sql-in-sqlite) got me started, and I've replicated it in the context of my application. But I can't seem to find a good resource explaining how this actually works. I'll run through where I'm not understanding, taking the first insertion into `client_update` as an example:

1. A new row, `(213310109, 'Janice', True)` is inserted on the `client_update` table triggering `tr_client_update`. The actions of this trigger happen after the insertion of the row, and before `(213310110, 'Jane', True)` is inserted.
2. The `INSERT` statement in `tr_client_update` compares the row `(213310109, 'Janice', True)` just inserted into `client_update` against `(213310109, 'John', True)` in `client` because they have the same `a_number`. Since the `name` has changed it logs the row from `client` in `client_log`.
3. Using the same logic, the `update` statement updates the `client` table with the new information.

I am hoping a kind DB Admin can help me understand the logical steps that are happening here. I don't feel like my explanation is adequate. Why is the right statement for achieving this `WHERE a_number = NEW.a_number AND (name IS NOT NEW.name OR docketed IS NOT NEW.docketed);` and not something like `WHERE a_number IS NOT NEW.a_number AND (name IS NEW.name OR docketed IS NEW.docketed);`. This would seem to make sense because what I want to check is that that the `a_number` is the same in both tables, but either `name` or `docketed` was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not actually a DBA question but rather a Boolean algebra question (which means it might be more at home on Stack Overflow.)

In short, you want the trigger to fire if **EITHER**:

- `a_number` is unchanged and `name` is changed (or not unchanged) **OR**
- `a_number` is unchanged and `docketed` is not unchanged.

We can then apply distribution (`(x AND y) OR (x AND z) == x AND (y OR z)`) to reduce the expression, as follows:

Your requirement, as I've restated it above, can be expressed as

```
(a_number = NEW.a_number AND name != NEW.name) OR (a_number = NEW.number AND docketed != NEW.docketed)
```

If we let

- x = (a_number = NEW.a_number)
- y = (name != NEW.name)
- z = (docketed != NEW.docketed)

we can rewrite it as

```
(x AND y) OR (x AND z)
```

which distributes to

```
x AND (y OR z)
```

and substituting our values of `x`, `y` and `z` we get

```
(a_number = NEW.a_number) AND ((name != NEW.name) OR (docketed != NEW.docketed))
```

The operators `=` and `!=` are equivalent to `IS` and `IS NOT` except that the latter should be used when one of the operands may be `NULL`.

I hope this helps.

Edit to add: Part of the OP's confusion was over the `NEW` element. `NEW` is a pseudorecord available to `ON INSERT` and `ON UPDATE` triggers which represents the record which fired the trigger, **as it will appear** in the table once the firing transaction is committed.

Comment: Hi Darwin, thanks for this thoughtful answer. I think part of my question was about boolean algebra, but really it was about trying to understand how these statements are executed and why this syntax works the way it does. First, I am confused about the syntax -- why would it by a_number = NEW.a_number, if we are checking that the a_number is unchanged. Shouldn't it be a_number != NEW.a_number? Moreover, I'm hoping for validation of my understanding that my description of the SQL processes running in the trigger is correct.

Comment: You want to find the record in `clients` whose case number is *the same as* the record being inserted into `client_updates`. 'The same' means 'equal', thus `a_number = NEW.a_number`.

Comment: This is precisely where I'm finding SQLite's syntax confusing. What does this `New` statement actually mean? Commonsense would suggest it means that the a_number is new, namely it's not already in the table the query SELECTs from, but instead it does the opposite. What I'm really trying to understand is the SQL syntax.

Comment: I think I've finally understood it. I was misunderstanding the `NEW` statement. What `NEW.a_number` translates to is the `a_number` that has been inserted. I was taking it to mean something like if the `a_number` is not equal to the `a_number` already in the table, in other words if it is new. I was confused by the syntax, but you've helped me clear it up.

Comment: You've got it. `a_number` is the value selected from `clients`, and `NEW.a_number` is the value that *will be* inserted into `client_log`.